# Arquivo JSON salva sem [ ] e sem as vírgulas entre os objetos

Tags: python, python-3.x, json

Tenho que criar um sistema para uma "pequena loja" poder registrar os produtos (em um arquivo JSON) e depois carregar o arquivo e fazer consultas com o mesmo carregado.

Estou tentando descobrir por que meus registros de produtos não estão salvando na estrutura correta do JSON. Não sei porque o JSON não está salvando os itens com o `[]` entre os registros.

```
lista_produtos = []   # <-- AQUI CRIO A LISTA QUE RECEBE REGISTROS DE PRODUTOS
contador_sinal = 0
contador = 0

class Produto: # <-- CREATING THE CLASS OF PRODUCTS
    def __init__(self, codigo, nome, descricao, valor):
        self.codigo = codigo
        self.nome = nome
        self.descricao = descricao
        self.valor = valor

def gravar(): # <-- E ESTA É A FUNÇÃO QUE SALVA A LISTA DE PRODUTOS EM JSON
    global contador_sinal
    print("="*50)
    print(" ","\nGravando Arquivo Externo dos Produtos...")
    with open('data.json', 'w') as fp:
        for item in lista_produtos:
            if type(item) == Produto:
                json.dump(item.__dict__, fp, indent=4)    
                fp.write("\n")
            elif type(item) == dict:
                json.dump(item, fp, indent=4)    
    time.sleep(1)
    print(" ")
    print("\033[32mARQUIVO SALVO COM SUCESSO!\033[0m\n")
    fp.close()

    contador_sinal = 1
    
    return menu()
```

Depois que faço o cadastro dos itens e chamo a função de gravar, as informações ficam salvas da seguinte forma no JSON:

```
{
    "codigo": 1,
    "nome": "test1",
    "descricao": "description",
    "valor": 10.0
}
{
    "codigo": 2,
    "nome": "test2",
    "descricao": "description",
    "valor": 20.0
}
{
    "codigo": 3,
    "nome": "test3",
    "descricao": "description",
    "valor": 30.0
}
```

Comment: Converta direto a `lista_produtos`, em vez de cada item dentro dela.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ele salva assim porque você está gravando cada objeto separadamente.

Se quer que tudo seja gravado como uma única lista, você teria que passar a lista toda para `dump`:

```py
# *** ATENÇÃO, AINDA NÃO FUNCIONA (continue lendo) ***
json.dump(lista_produtos, fp, indent=4)
```

Mas isso ainda não funciona porque a classe `Produto` não é serializável, portanto o código acima dá esse erro:

> ```
> TypeError: Object of type Produto is not JSON serializable
> ```

Isso porque o módulo `json` não sabe como serializar um `Produto`. Então temos que criar um [`JSONEncoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder) customizado, que sabe como fazer isso:

```py
from json import JSONEncoder

class ProductEncoder(JSONEncoder):
    def default(self, obj):
        return obj.__dict__
```

Quando o objeto sendo serializado não é um dos [tipos que o módulo `json` reconhece](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONEncoder), ele chama o método `default` acima. No caso, eu faço com que ele retorne o `__dict__`, como você estava fazendo. Mas você poderia colocar qualquer lógica que quisesse para deixar os dados da forma que precisar.

Depois é só informar no `json.dump` que você quer usar este *encoder*:

```py
with open('data.json', 'w') as fp:
    json.dump(lista_produtos, fp, indent=4, cls=ProductEncoder)
```

Com isso o arquivo terá a lista completa dos produtos no formato correto:

```js
[
    {
        "codigo": 1,
        "nome": "test1",
        "descricao": "description",
        "valor": 10.0
    },
    {
        "codigo": 2,
        "nome": "test2",
        "descricao": "description",
        "valor": 20.0
    },
    {
        "codigo": 3,
        "nome": "test3",
        "descricao": "description",
        "valor": 30.0
    }
]
```

---

E apenas para complementar, se quiser fazer o oposto (ler o arquivo e obter a lista de produtos), basta criar um [`JSONDecoder`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.JSONDecoder) customizado:

```py
from json import JSONDecoder

class ProductDecoder(JSONDecoder):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(object_hook=self.object_hook, *args, **kwargs)
        # todos os campos que um produto tem
        self.product_keys = ('codigo', 'nome', 'descricao', 'valor')

    def object_hook(self, dct):
        # se tem todos os campos de um produto (e mais nenhum outro)
        if len(dct) == 4 and all(k in dct for k in self.product_keys):
            return Produto(**dct)
        # se não é um Produto, retorna do jeito que está
        return dct

with open('data.json', 'r') as fp: # ler o arquivo
    # usa o decoder para criar a lista de Produtos
    lista_produtos = json.load(fp, cls=ProductDecoder)
```

Ou seja, se for encontrado algo que é um `Produto` (tem exatamente 4 chaves cujos nomes são "codigo", "nome", "descricao" e "valor"), o *decoder* cria o `Produto`. Senão, ele retorna o objeto lido sem modificação.

Comment: Cara, muitíssimo obrigado, deu certinho aqui!! Top demais, vlw mesmo